# Error while trying to unit test a sqlfunction: Unable to verify the expression, invoked 0 times

Tags: sql, unit-testing, moq, verify, automoq

I'm trying to unit test a sql function for my application, but when i try to  verify the method is only called once, it gives an error saying the method isn't called at all. I'm using moq to mock my different contexts and interfaces. The method is located in 'appointmentcontextsql'.

Tried to change what mock was mocking, but then it was unable to cast to different types.

Test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void CreateAppointment_IsValid()
{
    var appointment = new Appointment(61,23,24, DateTime.Today);
    using (var mock = AutoMock.GetLoose())
    {
        mock.Mock<IAppointmentContext>()
            .Setup(x => x.CreateAppointment(appointment));

        var cls = mock.Create<AppointmentContextSQL>();

        cls.CreateAppointment(appointment);

        mock.Mock<IAppointmentContext>()
            .Verify(x => x.CreateAppointment(appointment), Times.Exactly(1));
    }
}
```

Method to test:

```
public void CreateAppointment(Appointment appointment)
{
    try
    {
        _conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("CreateAppointment", _conn))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@questionID", appointment.QuestionId);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@careRecipientID", appointment.CareRecipientId);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@volunteerID", appointment.VolunteerId);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timestampAppointment", appointment.TimeStamp);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        _conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Expected the unit test to pass, as i'm just trying to see if the method is called correctly, but the mock.time method tells me it's invoked 0 times.

Comment: `IAppointmentContext` why do you expect that this is invoked?

Comment: Sorry i am fairly new to programming and moq, but i want to verify my method is invoked precisely once and i cant seem to get it to work. I thought the setup meant the method was invoked on the mock object.

Comment: In your specific case you don't need setup at all. But if you looked your test method where `IAppointmentContext` is used? It is not used at all so there won't be any invocation there.

Comment: In what way can i verify if the method is used in a correct manner without using the setup statement? I changed the cls var to create a IAppointmentContext, then it works. But then the live testing unit says the method is not covered

Comment: Actually the whole concept of unit test is to abstract external dependencies, like db, by introducing the abstraction layer. You should not write unit test which use db directly...

Comment: You can still `Verify` even you don't have setup. Sorry, don't understand the coverage problem...:(

Comment: I tried using the correct class (appointmentContextSQL), but then it throws a sqlexception about foreign key contraints, which means i try to insert a wrong foreign key value, which means the dependency to the database is still there, or am i wrong

Comment: Yes it is still there, look for example this article how to decouple that https://blog.kylegalbraith.com/2018/03/06/getting-familiar-with-the-awesome-repository-pattern/

Comment: I'll look into that, thanks for all the help